# select query issue in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have a mysql table below

```
ID     Name
1      AAA
2      BBB
3      CCC
```

Now I have a variable containing a random value of column Name.

```
$name = "BBB"; //Now this value can be changed that means it can be CCC or AAA
```

I want the output to be

```
ID     Name
2      BBB
1      AAA
3      CCC
```

If the value is CCC then the output should be like below. The row containing the value should be at the top and then rest of the rows.

```
ID     Name
3      CCC
1      AAA
2      BBB
```

And as usual I am stuck with the select query. The normal select query doesn't work as it selects only one item.

```
$sql = "select * from table where name='".$name."'";
```

Comment: Do you want to get the ID for C as 1? Or is that a typo?

Comment: I am trying to display all values from a table but the first row should contain the value passed in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `ORDER BY` with [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case.html).

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN name=? THEN 0
       ELSE 1
  END
```

Note that I have replaced injecting your php variable directly with a prepared statement (the question mark, PDO or mysqli).

In mysql it would be something like:

```
  CASE WHEN name="' . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . '" THEN 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='".$name."' 
UNION (SELECT * FROM table WHERE name!='".$name."')
```

Comment: Yeah, I had no idea about the FIELD() and CASE functions. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the FIELD( ) function in the ORDER BY clause you can achieve this. It works by specifying the column to sort by and then the values to sort in order. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY FIELD(Name, 'CCC') DESC;
```